# push new element into array in object in collection (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have some objects in my mongoDB

i try to update array in the object , but its not working

i look for many threads here and its not updating

the objects looks like this

```
const channelSchema = new Schema({
    cid: Number | BigInt,
    posters:[]
})
```

every object cid is diffrent ofcourse ..

so im trying to add element into posters Array by cid and not to all the objects in the collection

thats what i have tryied and its not working :/
i got deprection warning

```
Channel.update({'cid':123456},{$push:{"posters":11111}});
```

also tried this too , the res show its added but when i go to my mongodb its not there

```
await Channel.findOneAndUpdate({'cid':123456}, 
                    {$push: {'posters':11111}}, 
                    {new: true}, (err, res) => {

                    if(err){
                        console.log('ERROR:',err)
                    }
                    if(res){
                        console.log('RESULT:',res)
                    }
                   })
```

tried this too and same result as below

```
Channel.update(
            {cid:123456},
            { $push: { posters: 11111 } }
         )
```

this is the result i get

```
{
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818711+00:00 app[web.1]: n: 1,
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818713+00:00 app[web.1]: nModified: 1,
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818716+00:00 app[web.1]: opTime: {
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818718+00:00 app[web.1]: ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1580164353 },
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818720+00:00 app[web.1]: t: 89
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818723+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818725+00:00 app[web.1]: electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000059,
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818727+00:00 app[web.1]: ok: 1,
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818730+00:00 app[web.1]: '$clusterTime': {
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818732+00:00 app[web.1]: clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1580164353 },
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818735+00:00 app[web.1]: signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818737+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818740+00:00 app[web.1]: operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1580164353 }
2020-01-27T22:32:33.818742+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

where do i wrong ?
thank you.

Comment: When you use `.update()` it will result in `writeResult` which looks like `nMatched :1, nModified:1....`, but using `.findOneAndUpdate()`should return a document, Anyway try this `.find()` & check if any doc being returned or not :: `Channel.find({'cid':123456})`

Comment: Please share your mongoose version & connection code for mongodb